# Updated spyder 4.0.1 in a user defined environment(say abc) But when I open spyder after activating abc, still spyder 3.3.6 only opens

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I had installed spyder(3.3.6) in anaconda. As I don't have access to base directory, I created a separate environment and updated spyder to 4.0.1 with below command after activating that environment in Anaconda Prompt.

```
conda install spyder=4.0.1
```

When I opened Anaconda Navigator after updating spyder, the version of spyder is
[shown as 4.0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfEkB.png)

But when I launch spyder in the environment abc, the version 3.3.6 opens eventhough it is now updated to 4.0.1. I have no idea why this happens. I am also beginner in learning python. Can somebody help me out here?